# SDWebImage cell image view size wrong on first load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, imageview, sdwebimage

On first load of the table cell image, the image is "squished":

[image]

If I hit the back button, and then go forward it refreshes and looks fine:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?  Does it have to do with my placeholder image size or something somehow?  I just can't think of what it could be.

**View Controller:**

```
- (NSURL *)image {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.details[@"image"]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    return url;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = [self name];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Name";
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = [self email];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Email";
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = [self phone];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Phone";
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Img";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[self image]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                             completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                 // ... completion code here ...
                                 NSLog(@"Loaded: %@", image);
                             }];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: Where would you put this?  Like inside or outside of the completion block possibly, or somewhere else?

Comment: I think after the completion block